# Why are my C++ pointers suddenly diverging?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm creating a small AVL tree class in C++, and I'm getting a bit mixed up with pointers here, and its acting rather strangely.

In the class, **I have a variable named "root", which is a pointer to a node**. At one point, I pass a pointer of this object into the following function:

```
template <class T> void AVL<T>::RRotate(Node ** node) {
    std::cout << this->root << std::endl << *node << std::endl;
    *node = (*node)->left;      
    std::cout << this->root << std::endl << *node;
}
```

(Note that 'left' is a field that contains a pointer to a node).

Now, the first print is always printing out the same memory location.

However, the second call will print a different directory for this->root and *node.

Why is this? When I set "*node = (*node)->left;", shouldn't it be changing this->root too, since node is just a pointer to that pointer?

I'm a tad confused.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** A sample output is as follows:

> 0x902a88
>
> 0x902a88
>
> 0x902a88
>
> 0x902aa8

**EDIT 2:** Printing out &this->root and node instead reveals that they're always the same value, so it looks like the pointer is pointing to the right place.

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Literally just this->RRotate(node) (where node is set as a pointer to the root)

Comment: Why are you using Node**?  Presumably to mutate a pointer.  Thus, I would expect you to call it as this->RRotate(&node).

Comment: Node is already a pointer to a pointer, since its a pointer to root.

Comment: Can you do `cout << (*node)->left << endl;` before `*node = (*node)->left;`. I'm just curious.

Comment: My apologies, but I no longer have the malfunctioning code; I fixed the error. It was as @Inspired predicted - the root was not initalized properly. I'd delete the question, but I can't with an answer on it already

Answer (score 2):

You should call `RRotate(&root)` if you want `node` to be a pointer to `this->root`.

Or, more detailed:

```
node = &(this->root);
this->RRotate(node);
```

Most likely, in your code `node` just doesn't point to the `root` field. Try printing `node` and `&root`.

Comment: Checked that, but they are the same (see Edit 2)

Comment: I agree with Inspired. This snippet works fine: https://gist.github.com/Pikrass/2a5cc95d59eea3f161df

Comment: If you have two pointers with the same address, they **have to** point to the same value. Unless you have an undefined behavior somewhere (e.g. the `root` is uninitialized or the object is destroyed).

Comment: That's why I'm so confused! Root is intialized, no object is destroyed. There isn't anything in between what I put in the question

Comment: Probably the object was allocated on stack and went out of scope? Then printing with `cout` could change values in an unpredictable way. I'd recommend printing both addresses and both values before the `*node=` assignment and then after the assignment as well.